# NPOI and setCellFormula(): decimal-separator is cutoff

Tags: c#, npoi

I've a serious problem copying this formula with NPOI 1.2.5 from one cell to another with C#:

The original cell contain this:

```
=IF(H21>(H23*0.9997);IF(H21<(H23*1.0003);"OK";"Errore");"Errore")
```

The resulting cell reports exactly this formula, but with the decimal separator stripped. So I get this:

```
=IF(H21>(H23*9997);IF(H21<(H23*10003);"OK";"Errore");"Errore")
```

This is my debugger view right after the setFormula():

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks to be a bug. I'll check it.

Comment: I found the same problem. If I use sheet.SetCellFormula("10 * 0.015"), the result is "10 * 15" when the correct is "10 * 1,5".

Comment: Same bug on NPOI 2.0.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue [has been identified as a bug](https://npoi.codeplex.com/discussions/439089) form the developer. We can't do much more than paying attention to it and wait for a fixed release.